# Problema con BufferedReader en Java con Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Estoy empezando a programar en Java en Gradle, uso la IDE de NetBeans. Básicamente, estoy probando el uso del método switch a partir de un código simple, que le pide al usuario introducir en el teclado el número de mes que quiere que se imprima.

Mi programa es el siguiente:

```
       package switchcase;
       import java.io.*;
       public class Switchcase {
           public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                
               BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
               System.out.println("Ingrese el numero del mes: ");
               int mes;
               mes = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
               switch(mes)
               {
                   case 1: 
                       System.out.println("Enero");
                       break; 
                       
                   case 2:
                       System.out.println("Febrero");
                       break;
                       
                   case 3: 
                       System.out.println("Marzo");
                       break; 
                       
                   case 4:
                       System.out.println("Abril");
                       break;
                       
                   case 5:
                       System.out.println("Mayo");
                       break;
                       
                   default: 
                       System.out.println("El mes indicado no está configurado");
                       break;
               }
           }
       }
```

Y obtengo este mensaje:

[image: Informe de problema]

¿me pueden ayudar a resolver este problema por favor? No sé mucho, entonces una explicación en lenguaje para novatos sería apreciada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código es correcto pero el problema es que usas `readLine()` y gradle no está configurado para esperar un input. Para solucionarlo debes modificar tu archivo de configuración que por default se llama `build.gradle` si está escrito en Groovy o `build.gradle.kts` si está escrito en Kotlin. Dependiendo el lenguaje, agrega en ese archivo una de las siguientes opciones

```
// groovy
run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

// kotlin
tasks.run<JavaExec> {
    standardInput = System.`in`
}
```

Además para que los mensajes de gradle no interrumpan tu aplicacción puedes agregar la siguiente propiedad en tu archivo `gradle.properties` (si no existe crealo en la raiz de tu proyecto)

```
org.gradle.console=plain
```

Comment: ¡Funcionó a la perfección! Muchas muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola probe tu codigo y todo parece funcionar bien, lo unico que agregaria por seguridad es el llamado de la funcion `.strip()` para verificar que los caracteres de salto de linea o de espacio no se esten adicionando por error al momento de convertir la entrada que haces por consola, eso sucede porque el caracter de linea queda adicionado a la entrada asi que una asignacion a una variable quedaria asi:

`String variable = "3 ";`

o con el caracter de salto de linea `/n`

`String variable = "3/n";`

Lo cual no es posible convertir a un numero, para eso la funcion `strip()` remueve todos los caracteres que se consideran `whitespace` (espacio en blanco) eliminando los espacios y saltos de linea innecesarios, con ese cambio tu codigo quedaria asi:

Modificado:

```
mes = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine().strip());
```

============================================================================

```
package switchcase;
import java.io.*;

public class Switchcase {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero del mes: ");
    int mes;
    mes = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine().strip());
    switch (mes) {
    case 1:
      System.out.println("Enero");
      break;

    case 2:
      System.out.println("Febrero");
      break;

    case 3:
      System.out.println("Marzo");
      break;

    case 4:
      System.out.println("Abril");
      break;

    case 5:
      System.out.println("Mayo");
      break;

    default:
      System.out.println("El mes indicado no está configurado");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```